# Remove multiple entries from list python on basis of other list of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a scenario I have a array like  `['abc' , 'def' , 'cdc']`  and a list of object like `[{'key': 'abc'} , {'key':'cdc'} ]` so now I want to delete only strings from array which I have in key of list of objects .

currently trying this  `n = [x for x in n if x != 'abc']` but this is for single and don't seems good way to iterate everytime . so what can be best and effective solution here ?

Comment: Don't forget beginning of sentences. Read carefully please. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
n= ['abc' , 'def' , 'cdc'] 
d = [{'key': 'abc'} , {'key':'cdc'}]
print([x for x in n if x not in [value['key'] for value in d]])
```

Output

```
['def']
```

[value['key'] for value in d] is the extracted keys from the list of objects (or rather... dictionaries in Python lingo)